# Is there a method to calculate a dyadic fraction for given irrational number with least error?

Tags: fractions, irrational-numbers

For example $1/\sqrt{2}$ can be represented as $23/32$ or $181/256$?

Is there a standard method to generate dyadic fractions for given irrational number to approximate them? Dyadic fractions are quite handy since division by $2^n$ is merely a shift operation in computers. Therefore, this greatly simplifies multiplication with an irrational number.

Comment: Continued Fraction , for your example : $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx \frac{5}{7}, \frac{12}{17},\frac{29}{41},\cdots$

Comment: I need fraction that is dyadic i.e is of the form $a/2^b$ that is the aim